# How to do Oauth integration for WordPress Application?

Tags: wordpress, oauth

I'm trying to integrate Oauth for WordPress Application. I went through the documentation but I did not understand how to handle 'code' sent after authorize request has been made. Where should I keep the Code Authentication code block. I did not find any good tutorial for this, any link for a good tutorial would also be helpful.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the tutorial/documentation you're working with?

Comment: @Tom https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/ this is the link i'm following